# Xamarin XAML Grouped CollectionView Example not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been working on a complex collectionview for hours and after no success with getting it to emulate properly, I moved to a really simple example from Microsoft's website just to ensure it runs properly and I'm still having problems with it. I don't get any errors. When I emulate, I only see white space. Is there anything obvious that I'm missing in my code?

source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

Animal.cs file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Tester
{
    public class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AnimalGroup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Tester
{
    public class AnimalGroup : List<Animal>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public AnimalGroup(string name, List<Animal> animals) : base(animals)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

GroupedAnimals.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Tester
{
    public class GroupedAnimals
    {
        public List<AnimalGroup> Animals { get; private set; } = new List<AnimalGroup>();


        public void CreateAnimalsCollection()
        {
            Animals.Add(new AnimalGroup("Bears", new List<Animal>
        {
    new Animal
    {
        Name = "American Black Bear",
        Location = "North America",
        Details = "Details about the bear go here.",
        ImageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/01_Schwarzbär.jpg"
    },
    new Animal
    {
        Name = "Asian Black Bear",
        Location = "Asia",
        Details = "Details about the bear go here.",
        ImageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Ursus_thibetanus_3_%28Wroclaw_zoo%29.JPG/180px-Ursus_thibetanus_3_%28Wroclaw_zoo%29.JPG"
    },
    // ...
}));

            Animals.Add(new AnimalGroup("Monkeys", new List<Animal>
{
    new Animal
    {
        Name = "Baboon",
        Location = "Africa & Asia",
        Details = "Details about the monkey go here.",
        ImageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg/200px-Papio_anubis_%28Serengeti%2C_2009%29.jpg"
    },
    new Animal
    {
        Name = "Capuchin Monkey",
        Location = "Central & South America",
        Details = "Details about the monkey go here.",
        ImageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/40/Capuchin_Costa_Rica.jpg/200px-Capuchin_Costa_Rica.jpg"
    },
    new Animal
    {
        Name = "Blue Monkey",
        Location = "Central and East Africa",
        Details = "Details about the monkey go here.",
        ImageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/BlueMonkey.jpg/220px-BlueMonkey.jpg"
    },
    // ...
}));
        }

    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Tester.MainPage">

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
                IsGrouped="true">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="60"
                       WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Location}"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Looks right, but you don't show were you create/populate the 'Animals' property. Are you sure your viewmodel is properly set as the binding context of the page?

Comment: Hi , do you mean [this sample porect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/) also not works ? Have a check with `ViewModel` and how to bind it for **CollectionView** . You also can share your new created sample prject link here , I will check that .

Comment: @BenReierson Thanks for pointing this out! Apologies, I had forgotten to post my GroupedAnimals.cs file. I edited my post to include it. Do you see anything obvious that needs to be fixed in this file now?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have the download you've linked and have successfully ran the grouped collectionview within it on the emulator. However, when I tried to apply the concepts from this download to my own project, it didn't function. So I then found a simpler version (what I've referenced here in my post) to ensure I understand the basic concepts and can run it. But when I put  the code from the simpler example on Microsoft's site as written, it doesn't seem to function.

Comment: @boodaloo1 I see you have the method called CreateAnimalsCollection, which looks fine, but I don't see where/when you call it. The Animals property is a List, so if you add the items to it after the page has rendered, they won't show up, because there will be no events fired to tell the bindings to update. Make sure you are calling CreateAnimalsCollection, and consider changing Animals to an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @boodaloo1 Okey , you can share your created sample project link here , I will check that .

Answer (score 0):

I had not called the CreateAnimalsCollection() function in the MainPage. Once I added this in within MainPage.cs, the project functioned.

Comment: You could accept your answer , which will help more people who has similar problems .